# Making words occurring in a specific file available to company-mode

Tags: company-mode

I am using company-mode with `(setq company-dabbrev-other-buffers 'all)`.  Although this should search other buffers, I want that the words occurring in a particular files are made available for `company-mode` even when the file has not been loaded by the user.

I need something concrete enough to test, without using techniques that are net intended for the task.

Comment: Note that it is possible to provide a user-supplied list of words to `company-mode` for auto-completion via `company-ispell`. It may not be your exact requirement though.

Comment: Could you provide an example how to use `company-ispell` for what I want to do?  For what cases does the scheme fail to work as I need it?

Comment: You can check my usage of `company-ispell` from https://github.com/swarnendubiswas/dotemacs/blob/master/modules/init-company.el. I have a prepopulated list of words that are read from a file, and `company` offers them as completion candidates in addition to `company-dabbrev`. There is also https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-company-dict which prepopulates completions from existing files. You have to check whether these meet your requirements.

Comment: Things are not very clear and would need something concrete enough to test.